# code block in goroutine produces strange wrong results

Tags: go, goroutine

i have a big N*1 name array
i am currently using goroutine to calculate the edit distance of a name among each other

**the question is the results at [B] [C] are different**, maybe like

ABC BCD 7
ABC BCD 3

**there are 20000 records in names**

```
var names []string
```

**divide names into two chunks**

```
nameCount := len(names)  
procs := 2  
chunkSize := nameCount / procs
```

**channel**

```
ch := make(chan int)  
var wg sync.WaitGroup


for i := 0; i < procs; i++ { //create two goroutines
    start := i * chunkSize
    end := (i+1)*chunkSize - 1
    fmt.Println(start, end) //get slice start and end
    wg.Add(1)
    go func(slices []string, allnames []string) {
        for _, slice := range slices {
            minDistance = 256
            distance := 0
            sum := 0
            for _, name := range allnames {
                distance = calcEditDist(slice, name) //get the LD [A]
                sum += 1
                if distance > 0 && distance < minDistance {
                    minDistance = distance
                    fmt.Println(slice, name, distance) //[B]
                    fmt.Println(slice, name, calcEditDist(slice, name)) //[C]
                } else if distance == minDistance {
                    fmt.Println(slice, name, distance)
                    fmt.Println(slice, name, calcEditDist(slice, name))
                }
            }
            // for _, name := range allnames {
            //  fmt.Println(slice, name)
            // }
            ch <- sum
            // fmt.Println(len(allnames), slice)
            break
        }
        wg.Done()
    }(names[start:end], names)
}
```

i placed the calcEditDist @https://github.com/copywrite/keyboardDistance/blob/master/parallel.go

**PS:**
if i declare

```
var dp [max][max]int
```

in calcEditDist as local variable instead of global, the results are right, but is incredibly slow

**UPDATE 1**
Thanks all buddy,i take the great advice below in three steps
1) i shrinked the dp to a much reasonable size, like 100 or even smaller, DONE
2) i put the dp declaration in each goroutine and pass its pointer as Nick said, DONE
3) later i will try to dynamically alloc dp, LATER

the performance improved steeply, ╰(*°▽°*)╯

Comment: You cannot use `dp` as global variable if the function is to be executed concurrently! It will be shared by all the gorutines and the content of dp will be mixed. In addition, in the main() function of the github file, are you sure it is been executed in parallel? the `go parallel` will make it run in another gorutine but the loop is blocked reading from the channel so it will not run another `go parallel` until the previous one has finished.

Comment: hi siritinga.The github code was an old version, i have resoled the parallel problem of course.However, If dp is local variable, the 1024*1024 array will be allcated in every loop, it't extremely slow, it seem that the calc function is not goroution-safe, any solution?

Comment: I haven't tried, but it doesn't look like the problem is to allocate a millon-element matrix, it is not so much and you only have to do that the number of processors you have, so I suppose it will be 4 or 8 times. You should post your final version so people can check it.

Comment: hi siritinga, new version uploaded. Now it takes 6m17s to finish 20000 records

Answer (score 1):

As you've identified in your posting, having `dp` as a global variable is the problem.

Allocating it each time in `CalcEditDistance` is too slow.

You have two possible solutions.

1) you only need 1 `dp` array per go-routine, so allocate it in the for loop loop and pass a pointer to it (don't pass the array directly as arrays pass by value which will involve a lot of copying!)

```
for i := 0; i < procs; i++ { //create two goroutines
    start := i * chunkSize
    end := (i+1)*chunkSize - 1
    fmt.Println(start, end) //get slice start and end
    wg.Add(1)
    go func(slices []string, allnames []string) {
        var dp [max][max]int // allocate
        for _, slice := range slices {
            minDistance = 256
            distance := 0
            sum := 0
            for _, name := range allnames {
                distance = calcEditDist(slice, name, &dp) // pass dp pointer here
```

Change calcEditDist to take the dp

```
func CalcEditDist(A string, B string, dp *[max][max]int) int {
        lenA := len(A)
        lenB := len(B)
```

2) Re-write your `calcEditDistance` so it doesn't need the massive O(N^2) dp array.

If you study the function carefully it only ever accesses a row up and a column to the left, so all the storage you actually need is a previous row and a previous columns which you could allocate dynamically at very little cost.  This would make it scale to any length of string too.

That would need a bit of careful thought though!

Comment: Very great ideas, especially the dynamically allocation one